# How can I tell windows to backup opened files?

Tags: windows-10, backup

I just noticed Windows 10 Backup & Restore ("File history") does not backup a VHD file on my computer. I guess it is because the file is opened for write access.

In my company, we distribute software development environments with the repo, the configured IDE and some other stuff as a VHD file. So when a developer switches projects, we just give him the VHD, he mounts it, updates the repo, and is ready to go.

Usually, these VHD files are automounted, and this behaviour is now interfering with the backup strategy. If everyone has to close all programs started from the VHD and unmount it before making a backup, the windows 10 backup won't give any advantage over offline backup software like clonezilla. I thought the whole point of the file history is to not need to restart.

Does windows 10 not backup opened files? Is my guess correct?

How can I tell windows to backup opened files?

Comment: If you back up a file which is open for writing, the integrity of the back-up cannot be guaranteed, as parts of the file may change during the back-up process. This is particularly true of a VHD, where the master file table, directory entry, file contents and journal are all in different parts of the disc, so will be copied at different times. A work-round might be to make a copy for backing up before the VHD is opened.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A VHD is both - a file and a (virtual) disk. In this case, the property of being a disk wins: File History (if setup to do so) will process the individual files inside the VHD, not the VHD itself.

This is just the same as with your normal harddisk or SSD - not the block device, but the file system contents will be processed.

In addition to that, it would be inpractical to do, as a technical deficit in the backup system shows: It is unable to do partial copies, meaning that if you were to mount a VHD (which changes it by setting a flag) and unmount it without making any use of it, Windows would need to make a copy of the complete file which is likely to be Gigabytes of size. This is the reason, why big files are not easily included in file history.